# Python: Get part of string between appropriate braces and symbols

Tags: python, pairwise, pairing, braces

For if i have the following in a text file:

```
{
fun cake(){
"im cute"
subfun notcake(){
"dont close the question!"
}
}
fun notcute(){
"Did you just say..."
}
}
```

i want to get the stuff between two braces of the fun cake().
**Those particular braces, and matching pairs with opening and closing braces so that i dont get the strings of other braces.**

(the focused point is highlighted in bold)

Comment: what is your intended output?

Comment: You should use RegEx with the re library in python. Another aproach would be using the split method of an string , but this will only work if your structure is always the same.

Comment: also with regex, get the one of only the brace of fun cake()??

Comment: doesnt work, maybe because braces are on separate lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here's a general purpose library function I've created for you

```
def makePairs(code: str, bracket_list = ['[', '{', '(', '<']) -> dict:
    """
    Pair Maker
    =========
        Finds and creates corresponding pairs of all types of brackets given in the 'bracket_list' present in the 'code'.

        Parameters
        ----------
        1. Code : str - given string of code
        2. Bracket List : list - all types of brackets whose pair has to be searched and mapped

        Returns
        -------
        A dictionary that maps an opening bracket position to corresponding closing bracket position

        Example
        -------
        >>> bracePairs = makePairs(code)\n
        >>> for open, close in bracePairs.items():\n
        >>>    print(code[open : close+1])
    """
    
    naivePairs = { '{':'}', '[':']', '(':')', '<':'>' }
    pairs:dict = {}                                                         # maps '{' position to corresponding '}' position
    openBraceStack = []                                                     # will store the consecutive brace openings
    for pos, char in enumerate(code):
        if char in naivePairs.keys(): openBraceStack.append(pos)            # if char is '{', push it into the 'openBraceStack'
        elif char in naivePairs.values(): pairs[openBraceStack.pop()] = pos # if char is '}', pop the last '{' from 'openBraceStack' and store this pair into 'pairs'
    
    return pairs
```

### Usage (Have also provided in it's docstring):

```
bracePairs = makePairs(code)
for open, close in bracePairs.items():
   print(code[open : close+1], '\n\n\n')
```

### Query specific usage:

```
bracePairs = makePairs(code)
cakeOpen = code.find('{', code.find('fun cake'))            # find the first '{' after cake function
cakeCode = code[cakeOpen + 1 : bracePairs[cakeOpen]]
print(cakeCode)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. I just made a module using this way for my ease :)

Comment: Cheers!, creating modules is the best approach to programming